# How can I stop a symfony process which is listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000

Tags: php, linux, symfony

I am trying to run a basic Symfony installation which I generated using this command :

```
$ symfony new basic
```

When I run the following commands :

```
$ cd basic
$ php bin/console server:run
```

I get this error message :

```
[ERROR] A process is already listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000.
```

I suspect that a previous symfony process is causing this but I have no clue how to stop it.

I'm on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Terminal: lsof -wni tcp:8000
then you'll get a PID number, then terminal:
kill -9 PIDNUMBER

Comment: @Twinfriends Thanks a lot. worked like a charm.

Comment: Always happy to help. Had the same problem with my rails application a few weeks ago and then i found this, and it works for anything. Here is a link to the site i found the commands: http://tosbourn.com/killing-all-instances-of-ruby-on-rails-running-on-a-certain-port/ you can take a look at it if you're interested :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can stop the server using:

`php bin/console server:stop`

or you can force server to start even if previous one is running:

`php bin/console server:start --force`

For more info check the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/built_in_web_server.html)

Comment: The first one didn't help but the second worked well. Thank you.

Comment: That is deprecated

Answer (score 17):

This works on Symfony 5 & 6. Open the integrated terminal inside VSCode.

First stop the running local server:

```
symfony local:server:stop
```

Then start a new one:

```
symfony server:start
```

Open your browser and navigate to: 127.0.0.1:8000

If the command symfony is not recognized, then you need to install the Symfony as instructed here: [Install Symfony](https://symfony.com/download)

P.S. I noticed that on Windows machines, sometimes stopping the web server causes access denied error. Just re-run the command and it shall work.

Comment: `symfony serve:stop` is the shorthand of `local:server:stop`

Answer (score 16):

Better to use `killall -9 php` to kill all php scripts that are running.
Otherwise you wil start a new one while the previous one is still running.

Is probably caused by a infinite loop.

*Note: This will "kill" all running php scripts*

Answer (score 2):

First check what process is running on port 8000.

```
ps aux | grep 8000
```

You should something like:

```
username       94169   0.0  0.0  4427240    396 s018  S    18Jun19   6:43.42 /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.33_9/bin/php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 /Users/myuser/app...
```

Get the PID and kill it.

```
kill -9 94169
```

Re run the ps aux command and make sure the process is no longer there.
If it's still there you might need to run with sudo.

Your server:start should work after this.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Using `ps aux | grep 8000` did not work for me, I think it's because I'm using the stand alone web server rather than the bundle.

As per @Twinfriends comment, the following worked for me:

In terminal:
`lsof -wni tcp:8000`
This will show you the PID, which you use to do:
`kill -9 PID`
Replacing "PID" with your PID number

Comment: For me neither I would get a different pid everytime I'd ran that command, so I decided to simply restart the computer and fixed it .. ( in the process, decided to update my manjaro packages since I was going to restart anyways.. lol )

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the PID file if the kill command doesn't work.
`symfony server:start` writes a pid file to `~/.symfony/var/`.

Comment: Only thing that worked for me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can start the web server by:

`symfony serve -d`

`-d` will run the server in the background.

To stop a web server use:

`symfony server:stop`

`ctrl + Z` will stop the web server if you forgot to add `-d` at the end of the command.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was this (idk why but im posting it in case it might help someone

i simply restarted my xampp server and replayed the command and it worked.

Comment: Usually, you would not use Symfony's own server **and** XAMPP concurrently. Also, restarting XAMPP itself would not stop any other process